# Multiple instances in nested structures

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, nested

I was wondering if it possible to create/set multiple instance of a structure.

For Example if I had

```
Struct School{
    String Classroom;
    Student Child;
}

Struct Student{
    String Name;
    String Age;
}
```

Is there a way to save multiple names under same Elementary School?

School Elementary

Elementary.Child.Name = Jake

Elementary.Child.Name = Another name

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly what you want is

```
#define MAX_CHILDREN 10

Struct School{
    String Classroom;
    Student children[MAX_CHILDREN];
}
```

by making child into an array you can have  multiple instance of Student
 and you can then do :

```
 Elementary.children[0].Name = Jake;
 Elementary.children[1].Name = John;
```

you can also change children from an array to a vector :

```
std::vector<Student> children;
```

by changing it to a vector you get a dynamic array so you don't have to know how many children you need

** also if you use vector don't forget to include it

```
#include <vector>
```